# compare two list of unequal length and fill third list by unmatched index

Tags: python

I have two list of unequal size.

```
large_list=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
small_list=['A','D','E']
```

I have another list.

```
tag_list=['1','3','5']
```

I want to compare large_list against small_list. Where the elements are equal, at that point take the element from same index from tag_list, otherwise put '0' if the element of small_list and large_list are unequal at a particular index.

I tried this code

```
new_tags=[]
for lrg in large_list:
    for sm,tag in zip(small_list,tag_list):
        if sm==lrg:
            new_tags.append(tag)
        else:
            new_tags.append('0')
new_tags
```

But the ouptut produce has a larger length because of nested for loop but the length i want should be large_list

This is expected output.

```
output=['1', '0', '0', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using a lookup dictionary:

```
large_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
small_list = ['A', 'D', 'E']
tag_list = ['1', '3', '5']

# mapping each value of small_list to the correspondent tag_list value
lookup = dict(zip(small_list, tag_list))  # {'A': '1', 'D': '3', 'E': '5'} 
res = [lookup.get(e, '0') for e in large_list]
print(res)
```

Output

```
['1', '0', '0', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over `large_list` and use `index` to find its position in `small_list`. If the element is not present, then catch the resulting `ValueError` and instead insert a `0` at that position.

```
new_tags = []
for value in large_list:
    try:
        new_tags.append(tag_list[small_list.index(value)])
    except ValueError:
        new_tags.append(0)
print(new_tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pop and a comprehension to do this

```
large_list=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
small_list=['A','D','E']

tag_list=['1','3','5']

[tag_list.pop(0) if x in small_list else '0' for x in large_list]
```

Output

```
['1', '0', '0', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Comment: This only works if the elements appear in order, right?

Comment: Yes, it may break if the real use case deviates from the example

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
unmatch = []
large_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
small_list = ['A','D','E']
tag_list = ['1','3','5']
j = 0
for num in large_list:
    if num in small_list:
        unmatch.append(tag_list[j])
        j += 1
    else:
        unmatch.append('0')
print(unmatch)
# ['1', '0', '0', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

It first iterates `large_list` and if the value was not inside of `small_list` it will append 0 to the `unmatch` variable but if it exists, it will then append `j` index of the `tag_list` which each time the condition becomes true, it adds 1 to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iter` and `next` to fetch elements from `tag_list`:

```
it = iter(tag_list)
result = [next(it) if x in small_list else '0' for x in large_list]
```

However, this is fragile. What it there are more than three matching elements?